# Add Joomla login parameters

Tags: php, joomla

I work with joomla 3.1, and im a newbie..

I would suggest users to connect in two ways.
- First with the traditional way that is allready in production with Email address (like email@domain.com) and password
- Second, i would like to allow them to login with the phone application ID that they use.(like 4456544485) and password(same as the first way)

The login system used is the com_users component.
the phone application ID is in another DataBase (phoneapp) and has a email field.

But i don't know witch file i have to edit..?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Rather then editing the core files which I can tell you will result in drama, try looking for an extension on the Joomla Extensions Directory. If you edit the core files, upgrading to Joomla 3.2 will erase all your changes

Comment: thank you for your answer, i searched in the extension directory, but no result :(

Comment: in that case you're going to have to write a plugin. Have a look at @Laoneo's answer below which will get you started

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Writing an authentication plugin should not be too hard http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2:Creating_an_Authentication_Plugin_for_Joomla. I suggest to extend then your phone app plugin from the default Joomla authentication plugin https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/master/plugins/authentication/joomla/joomla.php like

```
JLoadder::import('authentication.joomla.joomla', JPATH_PLUGINS);

class PlgAuthenticationPhone extends PlgAuthenticationJoomla
{
    public function onUserAuthenticate($credentials, $options, &$response)
    {
        // Do your authentication with the number on the other database
        .....

        // if it failed do the fallback to Joomla
        return parent::onUserAuthenticate($credentials, $options, $response);
    }
}
```