# Joomla login plugin issue

Tags: php, plugins, joomla, authentication

i've created a new plugin for joomla 3.1:

i need this because i would suggest users to login with two ways. First with traditional email and pasword, a Second with a phone app id and the same password as the first way.

So i did this:

```
public function onUserAuthenticate($credentials, $options, &$response)
{
    $response->type = 'Joomla';
    if (empty($credentials['password']))
    {
        $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
        $response->error_message = JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_EMPTY_PASS_NOT_ALLOWED');
        return false;
    }

    // Get a database object
    $db     = JFactory::getDbo();
    if(is_numeric($credentials['username'])){
        $req = $db->getQuery(true)
            ->select('email_address')
            ->from('phoneapp.subscriber')
            ->where('username=' . $db->quote($credentials['username']));
        $db->setQuery($req);
        $result1 = $db->loadObject();
        if ($result1)
        {
            $username = $result1->email_address;
        }else{
            $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
            $response->error_message = JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_NO_USER');
        }
    }else{
        $username = $credentials['username'];
    }

    $query  = $db->getQuery(true)
        ->select('id, password')
        ->from('#__users')
        ->where('username=' . $db->quote($username));

    $db->setQuery($query);
    $result = $db->loadObject();

    if ($result)
    {
        $parts  = explode(':', $result->password);
        $crypt  = $parts[0];
        $salt   = @$parts[1];
        $testcrypt = JUserHelper::getCryptedPassword($credentials['password'], $salt);

        if ($crypt == $testcrypt)
        {
            $user = JUser::getInstance($result->id); // Bring this in line with the rest of the system
            $response->email = $user->email;
            $response->fullname = $user->name;
            if (JFactory::getApplication()->isAdmin())
            {
                $response->language = $user->getParam('admin_language');
            }
            else {
                $response->language = $user->getParam('language');
            }
            $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_SUCCESS;
            $response->error_message = '';
        } else {
            $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
            $response->error_message = JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_INVALID_PASS');
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $response->status = JAuthentication::STATUS_FAILURE;
        $response->error_message = JText::_('JGLOBAL_AUTH_NO_USER');
    }
}
```

When i logged-in with my email and password, no problem.
When i try with my phone app ID, i have a strange message...
**ERROR: This email is already registered.**

Comment: I would not just copy the entire code from the default Joomla plugin because if it changes in the future you have to apply the changes too, use the import. I've modified my answer here with the correct JLoader import http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20472619/add-joomla-login-parameters/20472768#20472768

Comment: Where do you get this error?

Comment: in the login page, this is the response...

Comment: i'm gonna try your changes

Comment: the authetication is made with two DB, not only one, the default users DB and my phone DB.

Comment: did you add some print_r and die statements?

Comment: yes, i have the good email from the first request in the phoneapp DB.
so $username = $result1->email_address is the good address

Comment: even if i make a print_r() & die; on $response, i have no error, but i allways have this message: ERROR: This email is already registered... I'll hang myself